# Wait for Modal to close in Selenium/C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Now that `ExpectedConditions` is deprecated and I can't use `ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated` to determine that a modal dialog has closed, is there a built-in easy way to determine that a modal dialog has closed using Selenium and C#?

```
public static void WaitForModalToClose(IWebDriver driver, int timeoutSec = 15)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeoutSec));       
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(modal.getBy());
}
```

This gives me a deprecated warning.

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866334/c-sharp-selenium-expectedconditions-is-obsolete

Answer (score 2):

Using nuget, search for DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers, import that namespace into your class.
Now you can do this:

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(modal.getBy()));
```

Find more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49867605/7745522