# Google search button click with selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning selenium but I can't seem to click the google search button with it.
What I am trying:

```
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "https://google.com";
        IWebElement searchBar = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        searchBar.SendKeys("Hello world!");
        IWebElement searchButton = driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnK"));
        searchButton.Click();
```

It fills the search bar with hello world properly but an exception while clicking the button:
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable

Comment: Does the search button have a class name?

Comment: There are 2 elements with that class name, the first one is not visible. You have to click on the 2nd one which is visible. Or use js to click on the first search button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are learning, I think it's a good exercise for you where you can use  `findElements` and then interact with the list item(s).

I can give you the idea then you have to implement it by your self which will give you more information rather just getting the answer.

You have to use `findElements` rather `findElement` as there are 2 elements with the same exact `name` attribute value.

```
 driver.FindElements(By.Name("btnK"))
```

This will give you list of elements. Then check the size it will be 2. 
Now click on the 2nd Element.

Or you can just use JavaScript to click on the `searchButton` from your original post.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.
Just clicked the last element.
 var searchButton = driver.FindElements(By.Name("btnK"));
            searchButton.Last().Click();

Comment: And you can upvote as a gratitude and also helps the future visitors to pick which answer worked.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be just calling [IWebElement.Submit()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Submit.htm) method like:

```
searchBar.Submit();
```

going forward I would recommend using [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) so you can ensure that the element is present in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and is clickable using [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) and [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) classes combination:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement searchBar = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("q")));
searchBar.SendKeys("Hello world!");
IWebElement searchButton = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("btnK")));
searchButton.Click();
driver.Quit();
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Comment: Selenium 'ExpectedConditions' is obsolete now! Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49866334/6296708

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath

it worked for me

```
        string searchBox="/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input";
        string searchBtn="/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/center/input[1]";
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "https://google.com";
        IWebElement searchBar = driver.FindElement(By.Path(searchBox));
        searchBar.SendKeys("Hello world!");
        IWebElement searchButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(searchBtn));
        searchButton.Click();
```

Let me nkow if xpath doesn't work for you

Comment: Please accept if it worked so that others can be helped. Thank you :-)