# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ElementExists'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to do an explicit wait to go around using Thread.Sleep(), but I'm always getting this issue with the ElementExists. I'm not sure if I'm missing a directive or I need to declare something.

[image]

**TestProjectDemo**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://bi7-azure.test.com/");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("appList")));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://bi8.test.com/azure/");
Thread.Sleep(10000);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://insightsmp.test.com/");
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

**BaseClass**(this is where I'm declaring the objects)

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;

namespace TestProject.BaseClass
{
    public class BaseClassTrigger
    {  
        public IWebDriver driver;
        public object wait;
        public object ExpectedConditions;
```

Comment: Can you show the whole file please?

Comment: Also please look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49867605/2501279

Comment: Please include code as text, not as images.

Comment: And read [tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) which states _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_. Ergo, you should not prefix every question with "Selenium C#" because you have already tagged your question as such.

Comment: The property name is clashing with the class name. Rename the property or refer the the class using a fully qualified class name.

Answer (score 1):

You have a property on BaseClass named ExpectedConditions. The property name conflicts with the ExpectedConditions class name in the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI namespace. Either:

- Rename the ExpectedConditions property in BaseClass or
- Use the fully qualified class name: OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions

Most likely the ExpectedConditions property in BaseClass was a mistake introduced by choosing the wrong option in the "Quick actions and refactorings" menu in Visual Studio when trying to resolve the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI namespace. I would just remove the ExpectedConditions property in BaseClass.

Comment: It's not accepting the fully qualified class name though, and the red underline is on ExpectedConditions saying "The name ExpectedConditions" does not exist in the current context".

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing **Selenium.Support**; however, it says that it is already deprecated, the recommended way around this is to make your own function from scratch and call that function whenever you need the wait condition.

Comment: The ExpectedConditions and PageFactory classes have been moved to another GitHub repository, which currently has no owner. Things like WebDriverWait are still supported.