# how to implement the explicit wait by using selenium powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium

i have to wait until an element has to be load in the page by using the Selenium powershell.

As a part of automation i have to load the portal and click the element. Implicit wait is not a good practice.

So please suggest the explicit waits with selenium powershell.

Regards
Vinay

Answer (score 4):

worked with the below option:

```
   $seleniumWait = New-Object -TypeName 
   OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait($driver, (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 60))
   $seleniumWait.Until([OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions]::ElementIsVisible([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::Id("idp-discovery-username"))) | Out-Null
```

$driver.FindElementById("idp-discovery-username").SendKeys($userName)

Comment: I am getting this error: `InvalidOperation: Unable to find type [OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions].` upon executing the 2nd line above. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot, it was fantastic! I search for the support dll and found it.

Comment: Works but ExpectedConditions is deprecated, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866334/c-sharp-selenium-expectedconditions-is-obsolete for an alternative

Answer (score 2):

```
Find-SeElement -Driver $d -Wait -Timeout 10 -Css input[name='q']
```

https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell

Comment: Thanks for your response. its an implicit wait, it will wait for 10sec to load the CSS element. if element will load a little longer then we are landing into the catch block. 

I would like to give a explicit wait: It has to wait certain time limit and presence of the element.

Eg: i will give the timeout as 100 sec, if the element has presence in less than 10sec then it will move further. Else it will wait upto 100 sec then failed.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$Condition = [System.Func[[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver],[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]]]{param($D) $D.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::XPath("THE XPATH OF THE ELEMENT"))}
# you can use other mechanism instead of xpath, like ClassName, Id, etc.
$WebDriverWait = [OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait]::new($Driver, [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(5))
$WebDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes([System.Type[]]([System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException]))
$WebDriverWait.Until($condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. its an implicit wait, it will wait for 10sec to load the CSS element. if element will load a little longer then we are landing into the catch block. I would like to give a explicit wait: It has to wait certain time limit and presence of the element. Eg: i will give the timeout as 100 sec, if the element has presence in less than 10sec then it will move further. Else it will wait upto 100 sec then failed.