# Selenium Issues finding element in an accordian

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on a report inside an accordian element.

Ive tried various methods to identify the element but nothing i tried worked.

With XPath and Id I get the following error message:

> OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable'

This is the code I've tried.

```
static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
static IWebElement element;

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportCreator1_DataListReports_3_LinkButtonReport_0\"]")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportCreator1_DataListReports_3_LinkButtonReport_0")).Click();
```

This is the HTML inside the accordion that I'm targeting,

```
<a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportCreator1_DataListReports_3_LinkButtonReport_0" class="ReportImg" href="javascript:__doPostBack           ('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ReportCreator1$AccordionReportList_Pane_3_content$DataListReports$ctl00$LinkButtonReport','')">All Assessments</a>
```

Comment: Double-check your locator is unique... open the dev console and try `$$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportCreator1_DataListReports_3_LinkButtonReport_0")`. Does it return only one element? It seems like a crazy long locator to NOT be unique... but I've seen issues like this before where there were 2 or more elements on the page and the first wasn't visible, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element might not be visible while interacting try use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `ElementToBeClickable()` and following locator.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportCreator1_DataListReports_3_LinkButtonReport_0"))).Click();
```

Or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[text()='All Assessments']"))).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks Kunduk, both worked. I have a small issue though. "ExpectedConditions" has a squiggly line under it and the message said "deprecated". I can lable it Obsolete but I was hoping you might have a solution?

Comment: @Lars7 : Using NuGet, search for DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers, and import that namespace into your class. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866334/c-sharp-selenium-expectedconditions-is-obsolete

Comment: @Kundak Thanks again, you have been very helpful

Comment: @Lars7 : Glad to be able to help.