# C# Selenium Driver - get all elements by text

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, automation

```cs
        private IWebDriver webDriver;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://localhost:44311/");
        }

        [Test]
        public void ButtonsCount_IsCorrect_IsTrue()
        {
            var buttons = webDriver.FindElement(...));

            ...
        }
```

Simple scenario - website contains dynamically created buttons. I want to ensure count of buttons is the same as expected.

Catching it by XPath would be easy, except XPath leads to certain element, here we want to catch multiple dynamically created elements, but each one looks like this:

```html
<a><i></i>Details</a>
```

The only difference is where `href` leads, and I have skipped classes because they are not important here.

Conclusions are, it wouls be wise to search for all `<a>` which contain string `Details`. Now question is, how to do it in C# driver.

Comment: Have you provided enough wait to load page properly? If you still get `list.Count` 0 then check if element present inside an iframe?

Comment: @KunduK I think it should be fine because `By.LinkText` works fine. But I still want to know how to solve it if I want to search for `div` or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findElements` with xpath to find List of elements:

```
List<WebElement> elementName = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'Details')]"));
```

Comment: List contains 0 elements, which is not true.

Comment: Add wait: `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement elementName = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'Details')]"));`

Comment: What is `ExpectedConditions`?

Comment: Please take a look for wait solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866334/c-sharp-selenium-expectedconditions-is-obsolete