# Waiting for elements with PowerShell and Selenium 4

Tags: powershell, selenium4

I am working on updating some PowerShell code that previously worked with Selenium 3.141. I have the following code snippet:

```
Add-Type -LiteralPath "$seleniumPath\lib\net48\WebDriver.dll"
Add-Type -LiteralPath "$seleniumPath\lib\net48\WebDriver.Support.dll"
$url = "https://<webpage.com>"
$options = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu")
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($options)
[OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait]$wait = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait ($driver, [System.TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(60))

$driver.Navigate().GoToURL($url)
$driver.FindElementById("username")
$wait.Until([OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions]::ElementExists([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::Id('username')))
```

With Selenium 4.0, FindElementById no longer works:

> Unable to find type [OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions].

As far as I can tell, OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions exists in WebDriver.Support, right?

Looking around for alternatives, I found SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers, but that maybe only works with .netstandard2.1?

Comment: Maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866334/c-sharp-selenium-expectedconditions-is-obsolete

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Looking closer, if I try to do the same thing with PowerShell, I get an error. ```$wait.Until((Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param([OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver]$dummy)
                    [OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]$element = $global:driver.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::Id("username")); return $element}))``` results in "Cannot find an overload for "Until" and the argument count: "1"." But ```$global:driver.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::Id("username"))``` does return the element (once the page is loaded).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, this worked for me:

```
Add-Type -LiteralPath "$seleniumPath\lib\net48\WebDriver.dll"
Add-Type -LiteralPath "$seleniumPath\lib\net48\WebDriver.Support.dll"
$url = "https://<webpage.com>"
$options = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu")
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($options)
[OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait]$wait = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait ($driver, [System.TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(60))

$driver.Navigate().GoToURL($url)
$driver.FindElementById("username")

$wait.Until([System.Func[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, System.Boolean]] { param($driver) Try { $driver.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::Id('username')) } Catch { $null } })
```

If you want to return the element object instead of a boolean value, you can just change "System.Boolean" (on the last line) to "OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement".

Comment: Nice work.  I stumbled upon this link yesterday which was interesting too (transposing some C# expressions into PowerShell) - http://www.reza-aghaei.com/net-action-func-delegate-lambda-expression-in-powershell/

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. It was the last bit that lead to my solution.

Comment: From where did you get `WebDriver.Support.dll`?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot, it was fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

The `ExpectedConditions` class was deprecated and removed according to the [.Net changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/dotnet/CHANGELOG):

> v3.11.0
>
> Marked .NET ExpectedConditions obsolete. Using the ExpectedConditions class provides no benefit over directly using lambda functions (anonymous methods) directly in one's code. Since the community appears to believe that an "official" repository of wait conditions is desireable, the existing code has been migrated to a new repository under a [new organization on GitHub](https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras).    It is hoped that this will encourage a volunteer from the community to take    ownership of this code. Users should update their references and migrate    their code to use `SeleniumExtras.ExpectedConditions`. This implementation    will be removed from the .NET language bindings in a future release

> v4.0.0a1
>
> Removed deprecated ExpectedConditions and PageFactory classes, as well as the supporting classes thereof.

Using scriptblocks in Powershell is similar to lamba expressions in C# as @StackExchangeGuy pointed out. To continue to use the `ExpectedConditions` class you could a) build `DotNetSeleniumExtras` from source and import it or b) downgrade to `v3.141.0`.