# Ultimate C# wrapper for WebDriver Wait and Click

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Having used WebDriver for many years, I have created methods that wrap the core Wait and Click. Can anyone see any problems with the code (it seems to work fine for me)

The try/catch seems to be the best way to stop false-positives and reduce the flakiness of tests

Is the for loop the best way to keep trying until the timeout?

```
public IWebElement WaitForElementToBeDisplayed(string elementCss, int maxWaitSecs=0)
{
    if (maxWaitSecs == 0) maxWaitSecs = Timeout;

    IWebElement webElement;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxWaitSecs; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            webElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(elementCss));
            if (webElement.Size.Width > 0) //.Displayed)
            {
                return webElement;
            }
            else
            {
                Wait(1);
            }
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            Refresh();
        }
        catch
        {
            Wait(1);
        }
    }
    var errorText = $"WaitForElementToBeDisplayed(): Element not displayed (Css={elementCss})";
    throw new WebDriverTimeoutException(errorText);
}
```

```
public BasePage Click(string elementCss, WaitForElement wait=WaitForElement.Displayed)
{
    IWebElement webElement = null;

    switch (wait)
    {
        case WaitForElement.None:
            webElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(elementCss));
            break;
        case WaitForElement.Displayed:
            webElement = WaitForElementToBeDisplayed(elementCss);
            break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Timeout; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            webElement.Click();
            return this;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            Refresh();
        }
        catch
        {
            Wait(1);
        }
    }
    var errorText = $"Click(): Element not clicked (Css={elementCss})";
    throw new WebDriverTimeoutException(errorText);
}
```

```
public BasePage Refresh()
{
    driver.Navigate().Refresh();
    Wait(2);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for SO. You are asking for a code review which belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. NOTE: Each site's rules are different so read their rules carefully before posting questions there.

Comment: Having said that, `WaitForElementToBeDisplayed()` 1. your code is reproducing `ExpectedConditions` which is already available and should be used instead. 2. You are forcing use of CSS selectors when you should be passing in a By to keep the methods more flexible. 3. If you want the default timeout to be to be some number, then use than number instead of 0. 4. Always refreshing the page when you get a `StaleElementReferenceException` is not a good idea because you could lose state on the page. Just refetching the element on the next loop is enough to "reset" that issue.

Comment: `Click()` 1. See #1 above, don't reproduce `ExpectedConditions`. 2. See #2 above, use `By` instead. 3. For `Click()` you should be using `ExpectedConditions` wait for clickable and not just visible. 4. If you attempt to click an element that is not visible, it will throw so `WaitForElement.None` doesn't make any sense there. There's more feedback I could give but those are the big ones that I see at first glance.

Comment: ExpectedConditions is 'deprecated' for C#, so I stopped using it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866334/c-sharp-selenium-expectedconditions-is-obsolete

Comment: I have noticed when running WebDriver tests with NUnit in Visual Studio that WebDriver seems to convert By.Id to Css, so now I use CssSelector for everything. An ID is prefixed with a '#' and a class is prefixed with a '.'

Comment: My WaitForElement.None seems to be similar to Playwright's Force

Comment: ExpectedConditions were just pulled out of the Selenium package and moved into it's own package. You can find it here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers. You can see the reasoning from one of the contributors, Jim Evans: https://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2018/03/deprecating-parts-of-seleniums-net.html

Comment: iterations !=seconds...  if using webdriverwaits and dealing with stale element and/or clickintercepted errors, the iterations will be timeout *2 (sleeps inside webdriverwaits are 1/2 second...)  You should check this answer for a similar method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820416/random-errors-using-wait-for-element-clickable-method-in-selenium/66820707#66820707  (You can also functionize and re-call the function if those exceptions are caught, keeping a global sanity count...)

Comment: I'm not sure what Playright Force you are referring to but the [force click](https://playwright.dev/docs/input#mouse-click) is not trying to click an invisible element, it specifically states that one of the conditions is to "wait for it to become displayed". Your `.None` is not waiting at all where you should be waiting for clickable if you are going to click.

Comment: @browsermator He's not using `WebDriverWait` so I'm not sure what point you are trying to make. Also, `WebDriverWait` by default polls at 500ms... polling time is independent of timeout time.

Comment: @browsermator ... but yes, I agree with your link because I wrote that answer. :) My click() method uses ExpectedConditions at it's core but also handles some common exceptions inside a `try-catch` and looping to try to get past the exception throwing within the timeout period.

Comment: yes, but should be using webdriverwaits... then timeout can be tied to iteration.  You don't necessarily need expected conditions, but I think they're very useful.  I think in C# you'd just put some bool checks in there for things like isVisible, etc...

Comment: @browsermator The code for `ExpectedConditions` is all open source so you can see how they implemented everything, https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras/blob/master/src/WaitHelpers/ExpectedConditions.cs

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers last updated 2018-03-11

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/support_features/expected_conditions/ ".NET stopped supporting Expected Conditions in Selenium 4 to minimize maintenance hassle and redundancy."

Comment: I have found that, for WebElements, all I need is 'exists' and 'is displayed' (size > 0)